# How to handle LocalDateTime stored as byteArray with migration from Spring boot 1.4 to 2.0.0

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, migration, spring-data-jpa

I am in the process of migrating my app from Spring Boot 1.4.x, and Spring Data 1.10.2 up to Spring Boot 2.0.0 and Spring Data 2.0.4

The latest issue I have, appears to be the change in Hibernate versions. I have LocalDateTime/LocalDate that were stored in the DB as blob byte arrays. They look like `\xaced00057372000d6a6176612e746.....` When I spin up the app with the upgraded dependencies. I get `Trailing junk on timestamp:` and `Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: {1}`.

I believe that Hibernate now looks to treat LocalDateTime/LocalDate natively as a timestamp. And the blob entries from the previous implementation (without using a converter). Are causing this issue.

Any thoughts on how to handle this?

An entity may have the following, as for dates where sort was important we did use a converter:

```
....

@Column("CREATE_DATE")
private LocalDate dateCreated;

@Column("TIME_STAMP_UPDATED")
@Convert(converter = MyLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime timestampUpdate;

....
```

Comment: I am working through the process of writing a custom Converter to handle retrieving data back from the DB. It feels ugly though. I will share more when I have something worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this by writing a converter. On a note, it appears that the team that originally built out the LDT to Blob converter as part of Hibernate ORM, didnt expect people to use it, but rather include the Java8 converters or apply their own converter as I did above on dates we required more precision.

I guess it does make sense to want to keep date in a DB as a TIMESTAMP or other more usable type, but at the same time I feel that if we build something, we should expect it to be used exactly that way. None the less, here is how I solved it.

We have 2 solutions available that I gathered.

1. Is to update our schema, convert all these blobs to TIMESTAMP and remove the old columns across the DB. Not a pretty solution.
2. Create a Mapper to force the ORM to handle the entity fields correctly. This, with Spring, was pretty trivial to do and the solution I am using, with success. Please, if you see something in my code that could be improved - comment! I would like to make sure I am implementing and sharing the best possible solution.

I Created a new Class.

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.time.LocalDateTime; 
... 
@Converter
@Log4j2
public class LegacyLocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Byte[]> {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        if(localDateTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try (final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer)) {
            oos.writeObject(localDateTime);
            return ArrayUtils.toObject(buffer.toByteArray());
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.error("Error occurred converting ldt to byte[], e.message: [{}], e.cause: [{}], e.stack: [{}], e" +
                            ".class: [{}]",
                    e.getMessage(), e.getCause(), e.getStackTrace(), e.getClass());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(final Byte[] bytes) {
        if(bytes == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try(final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(bytes));
            final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)){
            final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(objectInputStream.readObject().toString());
            log.info("Object: [{}]", dateTime);
            return  dateTime;
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.error("Error occurred converting byte[] to ldt, e.message: [{}], e.cause: [{}], e.stack: [{}], e" +
                            ".class: [{}]",
                    e.getMessage(), e.getCause(), e.getStackTrace(), e.getClass());
            throw e;
        }

    }
}
```

Then, my example in my first code block from my question becomes:

```
....

@Column("CREATE_DATE")
@Convert(converter = LegacyLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDate dateCreated;

@Column("TIME_STAMP_UPDATED")
private LocalDateTime timestampUpdate;

....
```

You will notice that I removed the Converter from my `timeStampUpdate` and applied our new Converter to `dateCreated`. Our original converter is no longer needed with Spring boot 2.0.0 with Spring Data 2.0.4 as it natively handles this now as mentioned. The new converter, in my case (tested with H2 and Postgres), handles the blob/byteArray objects stored in the DB and no longer throws the problematic errors.